# How can the delta method be applied here?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution#Related_distributions), the (centered and scaled) chi-distribution converges to the standard normal distribution:

> $$\frac{\chi_k-\mu_k}{\sigma_k} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)$$

Where by definition $$\chi_k = \sqrt{X_1^2+ \ldots + X_k^2}$$ where $X_j\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ are i.i.d.

The mean and variance (also from Wikipedia) are:

\begin{align}
\mu_k & = \sqrt 2 \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{k+1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma(k/2)}\\
\sigma_k & = k-\mu_k^2
\end{align}

I must be missing something elementary, but (assuming the cited limit is correct) I can't quite see how to apply the CLT.

I've tried the delta method but didn't find it helpful here.

---

Added: Concerning the delta method, it seems to assume $$\sqrt k \frac{Y_k-\mu}{\sigma} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)$$

and (under certain conditions on $g$) to imply $$\sqrt k \frac{g(Y_k)-g(\mu)}{ |g'(\mu)| \sigma} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)$$

So if we set $Y_k = \frac{X^2_1+\cdots + X^2_k}{k}$ and $g = \sqrt{\cdot}$ then $\mu = \mathbb E(Y_k) = 1$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{ \mathbb V (Y_k) } = \sqrt 2$, so $|g'(\mu)| = 1/2$. So we end up with
$$
\frac{ \chi_k - 1/\sqrt k }{ \sqrt 2 / 2 } \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,1)
$$ 
which is quite different from the above cited from Wikipedia.

Comment: Why didn't Delta's method help? You could consider $\chi_k^2 = X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2$ which is a (unnormalized) sample average and then apply Delta's method

Comment: @YiningWang: I ended up with something seemingly very different than I meant to. I updated the question to include my attempt to apply the delta method.